# Limit of $(n^\frac{1}{n}-3)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to find the limit of $(n^ {\frac{1}{n}}-3)^n$.

I know that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n^\frac{1}{n}$ is $1$, but I don't know in how far that could help me. I would be glad if you could help me.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want $(n^ {\frac{1}{n}}-1)^n$? For any $c > 1$, $(n^ {\frac{1}{n}}-c)^n$ diverges as shown by José Carlos Santos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^\frac1n=1$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n^\frac1n-3)=-2$ and therefore your limit does not exist.

Comment: Because $$(-2)^n$$ has no limit?

Comment: @Paul Right you are!